# probability of being within a 2D grid cell

Tags: probability-inequalities

Consider two joint-normal gaussian variables A and B with known probability density. A and B form a point in 2D space. What is the probability that the sample point falls within a rectangular grid cell. Can this be solved in closed form (including an erf())?  Simplification: A and B are zeromean and are uncorrelated. The grid cell is square and centered at (0,0).

Comment: Is this homework? Are the rectangle sides parallel to the axes? For the simplified versions, the answers are standard and can be found written down explicitly in lots of places.

Comment: Because any solution would be affinely equivalent to finding the probability of an arbitrary parallelogram for a standard Bivariate Normal distribution, I believe the answer is in the negative.